# Alamofire decoding by index of array

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, decodable

I have problem with decoding of json , I can't use 'self' function on the struct , because I get json from the server by 1 key (which name "my_profile") and many values , which I return by index , and I want to decode it to the struct , pls help me

```
Alamofire.request(mainUrl, method:.post , parameters: paramstring , encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
    response in
    if let data = response.data
    {
        switch response.result
        {
        case.failure(let error):
            print(error)
        case.success(let value):
            let json=JSON(value)
            guard let dataarr = json["my_profile"].array else { return }
            // I wan't send it to the structure , and get it from another view controllers
            var name = dataarr[0]
            var last_name = dataarr[1]
            var email = dataarr[2]

        }
    }
}
```

This is my Structure

```
struct UserInfo : Decodable {

    var name : String 
    var last_name : String
    var emai : String

    }
```

Json structure:

[image]

Comment: You should point out that you are using `SwiftyJSON`

Comment: I should print my json?

Comment: Yes, it would be helpful

Comment: added to description

Comment: create UserInfo object and set values to it and also take UserInfo array add every record to array

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to write an initialiser for your `struct`:

```
struct UserInfo : Decodable {
    var name : String
    var last_name : String
    var email : String

    init(name: String, lastName: String, email: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = lastName
        self.email = email
    }
}
```

Then you can use something like this (Adapt it to your specific needs):

```
let json = JSON(value)
guard let dataarr = json["my_profile"].arrayValue else { return }
let stringArray = dataarr.map { $0.stringValue }

var name = stringArray[0]
var last_name = stringArray[1]
var email = stringArray[2]

let userInfo = UserInfo(name: name, lastName: last_name, email: email)
// use `userInfo` object
```

To pass the object to a new view controller you should define a variable in the `NewViewController` to store the `userInfo` object:

```
let userInfo: UserInfo!
```

Then from the code above you should call these lines at the end (it uses storyboard):

```
// ...
let userInfo = UserInfo(name: name, lastName: last_name, email: email)

let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewViewController") as! NewViewController
controller.userInfo = userInfo
present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Where `NewViewController` is the new controller when you'll show the `userInfo` object content. Don't forget to set the new view controller identifier to `NewViewController` in the storyboard.

Comment: can I use this value in another view controllers , for showing in view

Comment: sure, you only need to pass it to the new view controller

Comment: yo man , can you give to me solution of initializing in another controller ) sorry